# purrr::lift_vd doesn't work with some functions

Tags: r

I have te following data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0), 
  y = c(0, 2, 1, 2, 1), 
  z = c(0, 2, 1, 2, 1)
)
```

And code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(var = pmap(., lift_vd(..f = sum, na.rm = TRUE)))

  x y z var
1 0 0 0   0
2 1 2 2   5
3 0 1 1   2
4 2 2 2   6  
5 0 1 1   2
```

It's ok. But, when I want compare multiple columns with `if_else`, for example, this function doesn't work. See:

```
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(var = pmap(., lift_vd(..f = if_else(length(unique(.)) == 1, 'ok', 'nok'))))
```

> Error in ..f(c(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0)) : could not find function "..f"

What's error? I need solution only with `lift_vd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = pmap_chr(., lift_vd(function(x) if_else(n_distinct(x) == 1, "ok", "nok"))))

  x y z var
1 0 0 0  ok
2 1 2 2 nok
3 0 1 1 nok
4 2 2 2  ok
5 0 1 1 nok
```

You don't really need `lift_vd()` here, using `c(...)` is slightly more compact and will give the same result:

```
df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = pmap_chr(., ~if_else(n_distinct(c(...)) == 1, "ok", "nok")))
```

Comment: What is `c(...)` doing here?